# Question Deletion

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I'm not sure if it contributes to our site stats, but one possible way to increase our answer / question ratio would be to delete some of the closed questions that have no useful answers.  Even if it doesn't help the ratio it would be nice for overall site cohesiveness.

I've cast some delete votes and I hope that my fellow mod-tool priviligees will follow suit :)

He's looking at you:

[image]

### on edit

#### from the FAQ:

> When should I delete questions?
>
> Closed questions that are of no
> lasting value whatsoever should be
> flagged and deleted.
>
> (Before voting to delete, please check
> that there are no good answers -- if
> so, then the question should be
> flagged for moderator attention as a
> potential merge candidate. We don't
> like to lose great answers!)

Comment: Do closed questions contribute to the Q:A ratio?

Comment: @kyle: i would love to know the answer to that, but either way it doesnt hurt to tidy up.

Comment: @dori: can you link to any info regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a search of all closed questions with no answers that are potentially dragging our ratio down:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A0+closed%3A1

Not all of these should be deleted, of course, but it's a good place to start.